# Optimizing game speed - Method of drawing ordered isometric tiles in a 2D game

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a game, the map size is `20*36` tiles means 720 tiles.

I have three layers in my game:

- The floor layer: Safe zone floor, Regular floor)
- Objects (Big rock, Small rock, Action tile) . (Action tile is for example, a tile that shows a wind, so when stepped on that tile, your character will move to the wind direction)
- Player's ships

So no, I can't just draw everything in the same loop, like that, because player entities are not using the same list as objects and floor layer, and floor layer is basically an array of `20*36`.

The thing is, I could just make them all implement some `Drawable` interface, and put them all in a list and draw with one loop, but I can't just draw them with a randomized order. The position of the object matters, if to draw the rock over the ship, or the ship over the rock.

Currently that's how I am drawing the objects and sea floor layer:

```
    Cell[][] sea = blockadeMap.getSea();
    Wind[][] winds = blockadeMap.getWinds();
    Whirlpool[][] whirls = blockadeMap.getWhirls();

    for (int i = 0; i < sea.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < sea[i].length; j++) {
            TextureRegion region = sea[i][j].getRegion();

            int x = (i * GameTile.TILE_WIDTH / 2) - (j * GameTile.TILE_WIDTH / 2) - region.getRegionWidth() / 2;
            int y = (i * GameTile.TILE_HEIGHT / 2) + (j * GameTile.TILE_HEIGHT / 2) - region.getRegionHeight() / 2;

            batch.draw(region, x, y);

            if (winds[i][j] != null) {
                region = winds[i][j].getRegion();

                x = (i * GameTile.TILE_WIDTH / 2) - (j * GameTile.TILE_WIDTH / 2) - region.getRegionWidth() / 2;
                y = (i * GameTile.TILE_HEIGHT / 2) + (j * GameTile.TILE_HEIGHT / 2) - region.getRegionHeight() / 2;

                batch.draw(region, x, y);
            }
            else if (whirls[i][j] != null) {
                region = whirls[i][j].getRegion();

                x = (i * GameTile.TILE_WIDTH / 2) - (j * GameTile.TILE_WIDTH / 2) - region.getRegionWidth() / 2;
                y = (i * GameTile.TILE_HEIGHT / 2) + (j * GameTile.TILE_HEIGHT / 2) - region.getRegionHeight() / 2;

                batch.draw(region, x, y);
            }
        }
    }
```

And this happens every frame draw, iterates 720 times per frame. 
I think I really need to find a way to optimize that.

In addition, after this, I have an iterator through all players and draw players.

What is the best way to handle such drawing?

Comment: One way is to use a z-buffer, but I think in your case that would be sub-optimal. What's wrong with sorting on depth?

Comment: @TassosBassoukos What does that mean?

Comment: A Z-buffer is when each pixel knows the depth it's at, so that draw operations may or may not affect it because draw operations have a depth value associated with them.

Comment: The other way is to give each Drawable a depth (how far away they're at) and then sort the list based on the depth so that far away elements are drawn before the near ones.

Comment: You know, in my game, the more far you are, the first you will get drawn. e.g if ship is at 0,0 and other is at 1,1, ship that is at 1,1 will draw first, and ship at 0,0 will draw after and will overlap the one thats at 1,1, so you can say that it's depth, cant you? @TassosBassoukos

Comment: Question- Do you really have to re-draw every frame?

Comment: Couldn't you just use tiled map editor and save yourself the hassle of coding maps?